# How To Get Dynamic Child Value Inside Dynamic Parent (DIV) While Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have question regarding dynamic object HTML where I think it's complicated. I need to read value of children object where it's dynamic inside parent div also dynamic.

It's so hard to me to find a right script where I can read children object value accordingly and keep as a group data before post to server.

Let me show you an example of my script below same as appear on firefox firebug:-

```
<div id="divtrans[]" class="purchase-items">
  <input type="button" name="tripno[]" value="PB" class="field btn-field">
  <input type="text" name="busno[]" value="XX001" class="field txt-field">
  <input type="text" name="amount[]" value="500" class="field txt-field">
  <input type="button" id="btnhideshowdiv" class="hideshow-div btn-remove" style="border:solid">
  <div id="comission" style="margin-left:25px;background-color:antiquewhite">
    <label style="float:left; margin-right:100px;">Commision</label><label>Amount</label>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Advance
        <input type="text" name="txtadvance[]" value="60" />
      </li>
      <li>
        Pay Trip
        <input type="text" name="txtpaytrip[]" value="60" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="divexpeses" style="margin-left:25px;background-color:antiquewhite">
    <label style="float:left; margin-right:100px;">Expenses</label><label>Amount</label>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Advance
        <input type="text" name="txtpetrol[]" value="70" />
      </li>
      <li>
        Pay Trip
        <input type="text" name="txtticket[]" value="70" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="divtrans[]" class="purchase-items">
  <input type="button" name="tripno[]" value="PB" class="field btn-field">
  <input type="text" name="busno[]" value="XX002" class="field txt-field">
  <input type="text" name="amount[]" value="1000" class="field txt-field">
  <input type="button" id="btnhideshowdiv" class="hideshow-div btn-remove" style="border:solid">
  <div id="comission" style="margin-left:25px;background-color:antiquewhite">
    <label style="float:left; margin-right:100px;">Commision</label><label>Amount</label>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Advance
        <input type="text" name="txtadvance[]" value="80" />
      </li>
      <li>
        Pay Trip
        <input type="text" name="txtpaytrip[]" value="80" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="divexpeses" style="margin-left:25px;background-color:antiquewhite">
    <label style="float:left; margin-right:100px;">Expenses</label><label>Amount</label>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Advance
        <input type="text" name="txtpetrol[]" value="90" />
      </li>
      <li>
        Pay Trip
        <input type="text" name="txtticket[]" value="90" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

As you can see I have 2 divtrans[] as parent where each parent have:-

```
tripno[]
busno[]
amount[]
```

then have a 2 div with children also

```
divcommision[]
txtadvance[]
txtpay[]

divexpenses[]
txtpetrol[]
txtticket[]
```

All this have value and I need to collect all value and write like below as string:-

```
parent1/PB,XXX001,500/60,60/70,70

parent2/PB,XXX002,1000/80,80/90,90
```

What I already done on my function like this below where still not working regarding read children value while loop:-

```
function readparentchildelement() {
  var tdivtrans=0;
  var dt
  tdivtrans= $('div.purchase-items').length
  for (start = 0; start < tdivtrans ; start++) {
    //$.each($('div.purchase-items').parents(), function (index, value) {
    //read parent div one by one
    alert($('.purchase-items').index(start));
    dt="parent" & start &"/"                                       

    var ch
    //then read tripno[] busno[] amount[]
    ch=$('.purchase-items').index(start).($('tripno')[start]).val());
    ch= ch & "," & $('.purchase-items').index(start).($('busno')[start]).val());
    ch= ch & $('.purchase-items').index(start).($('busno')[start]).val()) & "/";
    alert(ch);

    var chDiv1
    //read child inside divcommison

    var chDiv2
    //read child inside divexpenses

    //--loop ++ read next children
    //});
    } 
  $("#txtMyValue").Val(pr & ch & chDiv1 & chDiv2);
}
```

I don't know what a right syntax to make it run, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

One correction to your html. It is not recommended to have two elements with same id. So, I would really suggest you to make comission and divexpeses have classes with these names and not as ids. This will make your life much easy.

I was unable to understand how you construct the string you are requesting, hence I've created a dummy object and I'm printing it all to the console. Here is the link to to the fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/sniper6/9L9of9yj/). I've modified the HTML to have comission and divexpese as classes. Just open the dev tools and check out the console. It reads something like this:

```
parent 1
tripno -> PB
busno -> XX001
amount -> 500
txtadvance -> 60
txtpaytrip -> 60
txtpetrol -> 70
txtticket -> 70
--------------------
parent 2
tripno -> PB
busno -> XX002
amount -> 1000
txtadvance -> 80
txtpaytrip -> 80
txtpetrol -> 90
txtticket -> 90
--------------------
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your helping and I would try adopt you code to make it run on my situations. I will get back to you for the result. Thanks again Maaz Syed Adeeb.

Comment: After following your code I manage to get what I want. I like to know if I want do some automatically calculation let say I put value on txtpetrol=90 and txticket=90 on the Amount on div Expenses inside Parent 2 will show 180 while I keyin? Do you think jquery can do it that because how to determine which parent of this child I keyin to show a result.

Comment: I believe you are asking something which is a combination of jquery .change() and .parent(). Maybe you could ask another question regarding this.

Comment: I post new question regarding this matter:- **  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39319488/automatically-calculate-and-show-result-on-dynamic-parent-while-keyup-on-dynamic) ** Hope you can reply it. Thanks you for sharing your knowledge and helping me. I am totally new in javascript/jquery functionality. Thanks again.