# Automatically Calculate And Show Result On Dynamic Parent While KeyUp on Dynamic Child TextBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is still regarding dynamic parent and dynamic child where my issue is to automatically do calculation while key-up function.

All the script you can find at [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39316055/how-to-get-dynamic-child-value-inside-dynamic-parent-div-while-loop/39316702#39316702)

I also already add class on each div and input to make it better as suggestions.

```
<div id="divexpeses" **class="expenses"** style="margin-left:25px;background-color:antiquewhite">
    <label style="float:left; margin-right:100px;">Expenses</label><label>Amount</label>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Advance
        <input type="text" name="txtpetrol[]" class="field1" value="90" />
      </li>
      <li>
        Pay Trip
        <input type="text" name="txtticket[]" class="field1" value="90" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Now. Let me show my function where actually I need do automatically calculate and should be show up accordingly on parent div:-

```
$(".purchase-item").keyup('.field1', function (index, value) {
                alert("hai");
                // get current index position of the div
                var itemIndex = $(this).parents('expenses').children('.field1').index($(this).parent('.field1'));
                alert(itemIndex);
            });
```

Your must remember this is dynamic parent and dynamic child!

Each time I insert value on txtpetrol[] txtticket[] result be determine first which Parent Index and div Expenses. Then it should show at like below:-

```
Expenses       Amount   -- to -->     Expenses      Amount: 180
```

Any idea how overcome this issue? I need help please.

Thanks on advance for reading and replying my question.

Comment: No `.purchase-items-fieldset` element appears at `html` at Question? Are you try to determine which `.field1` element is active, or index of `.expenses` element?

Comment: Thanks you for replying. Can you please look my previous question. All script are there and I just add class to make it better as suggestions. Please click my previous question.

Comment: If your previous Question is actual Question, perhaps resolve that Question before posing duplicate Question?

Comment: My previous question more on parent child value. This question like are similar but how to determine which parent of this child while key-up. I totally lost to figure it out and I am sorry because I not good in jquery function. I am still beginner on learning process.

Comment: Are you trying to determine which `.expenses` element has `.field1` element which triggered `keyup` event?

Comment: Yes. but since .expenses also dynamic div than I need to determine which actually are.  That's the problem and I dont know which syntax should I use.

Comment: Note, `html` at previous Question contains duplicate `id`s. `Element.id` should be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I must say thanks to @guest271314 where show it code and I appreciate. I trying to adopt it, but it's not suitable on my situation and I keep thinking it's should be more simple than that.

Before I sleep I just trying this syntax like below and I got what I want:-

```
$(".purchase-items").keyup('.expenses', function (index, value) {
                // get current index position of the div
                dt2 = 0;
                var itemIndex = $(this).index();
                alert(itemIndex);
                //var items = $(".expenses").index(); //current div expenses
                //find input(.field2) inside div(.expenses) as parent
                $(this).find('.field2').each(function(){
                    var innerDivId = $(this).val();
                    if (innerDivId == '') { innerDivId = "0" };
                    //do calculation
                    dt2 = (Number(dt2) + Number(innerDivId));
                    alert(innerDivId);
                });
            });
```

I not sure why it workable, sum all input on based div and show a correct result because I am very very new on jquery function.

Comment: I think I need to wrap it more because above solution where I need to write twice function for .keyup('.expenses')  and .keyup('.commision'). This waste a such of process. How I can detect which are keyup on $(".purchase-items").keyup then using IF to determine either I click on .keyup('.expenses')  **OR** .keyup('.commision'). I think that more logic and clean code. Please help me if anybody know to construct back this function???

Answer (score 0):

`id` of element in `document` should be unique. Remove duplicate `id`s from `.expenses` element, use event delegation and `.index()` to determine which `.expenses` element triggered `keyup` event

```js
$(document).on("keyup", ".expenses", function(event) {
  console.log(".expenses index:", $(this).index(".expenses") 
              , "event target:", event.target);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="expenses" style="margin-left:25px;background-color:antiquewhite">
  <label style="float:left; margin-right:100px;">Expenses</label>
  <label>Amount</label>
  <ul>
    <li>
      Advance
      <input type="text" name="txtpetrol[]" class="field1" value="90" />
    </li>
    <li>
      Pay Trip
      <input type="text" name="txtticket[]" class="field1" value="90" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="expenses" style="margin-left:25px;background-color:antiquewhite">
  <label style="float:left; margin-right:100px;">Expenses</label>
  <label>Amount</label>
  <ul>
    <li>
      Advance
      <input type="text" name="txtpetrol[]" class="field1" value="90" />
    </li>
    <li>
      Pay Trip
      <input type="text" name="txtticket[]" class="field1" value="90" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="expenses" style="margin-left:25px;background-color:antiquewhite">
  <label style="float:left; margin-right:100px;">Expenses</label>
  <label>Amount</label>
  <ul>
    <li>
      Advance
      <input type="text" name="txtpetrol[]" class="field1" value="90" />
    </li>
    <li>
      Pay Trip
      <input type="text" name="txtticket[]" class="field1" value="90" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```